# How do I get the value of a row of HTML table in an aura iteration with onclick?

Tags: lightning, table, aura-iteration

I am trying to make a functionality where my lightning component shows a table of records and I want to make it so if you click a records row, it autofills my form with that records information.

Here is a snippet of my code right now. From what i've tried I can only get the  values and not the  but I just want it so you can click anywhere on the row and it logs the row information.

Component

```
<tbody>
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.CTransactions}" var="CT" indexVar="indx">
  <tr  title="{!indx}" value="{!CT.Id}" onclick="{!c.test}">
   <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!CT.Id}">{!CT.Name}</div></td>
   <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="StartDate">{!CT.Billing_Period_Start__c}</div></td>
   <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="EndDate">{!CT.Billing_Period_End__c}</div></td>
   <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="itemCount">{!CT.No_of_Items__c}</div></td>
  </tr>
 </aura:iteration>
</tbody>
```

js controller

```
test : function(component, event, helper)
{
    var target = event.target.getAttribute('title'); //|| event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('value') || event.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('value');
    console.log(target);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want get entire row item value when ever click any where in the row, should get by only via index. in your case please try with below code i already tested and let me know if any issue.

SEtesting.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
 <aura:attribute name="CTransactions" type="List" default="[]"></aura:attribute>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}"></aura:handler>
<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer"> 
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="First Name">Tester</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Last Name">Name</div>
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
         <aura:iteration items="{!v.CTransactions}" var="item" indexVar="index">
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps" data-record="{!index}" onclick="{!c.test}">
                <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="job">{!item.job}</div></td>
                <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="StartDate">{!item.Name}</div></td>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>

<lightning:input label ="seelcted row" aura:id="selecteditem" value=""></lightning:input>
```

SEtestingController.js

```
({
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var items = [];

    items.push({'job' : 'elctrical', 'Name' : 'abc'});
    items.push({'job' : 'fitter', 'Name' : 'xyz'});

    component.set("v.CTransactions",items);

},
 test : function(component, event, helper)
{
    var target = component.get("v.CTransactions")[event.currentTarget.dataset.record],
        selectedrow = JSON.stringify(target);
      component.find("selecteditem").set('v.value', selectedrow);
    console.log(target);
},
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this works? For me locker service did not allow to access html data properties of tr

Comment: yes it's work for me , edited with tested code and image

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate, you can create a separate component to display the row. On click, you know certainly the record/ value to used.

Also, to improve design further

1. Create a row component to display individual row
2. From row component invoke an event with the details of selected row (let's say, **showTransaction**)
3. Create a separate component to show edit form. This should handle **showTransaction** event and show details, as per data provided in event parameters.